# How to move multer upload midddleware to another file

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, multer

Working with `multer` and `gridFS` for an express API I am developing. I am having trouble moving the upload object to another file. I have setup `multer` so that

```
export const upload = multer({
    storage,
});
```

The following code works in `index.ts` where `multer` is initiated but not in any other routes file.

```
router.post("/upload", single("image"), (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    if (!file) {
        const error = new Error("Please upload a file");
        res.send(error);
    }
    res.send(file);
});
```

It's not possible for me to post a whole snippet but I hope this is enough.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve this by adding the following:

```
app.use(
    multer({
        storage,
    }).single("image")
);
```

Now that might mean it will run for every route which is another issue to address

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

for all path

```
app.use('*', multer({storage}).single("images"));
```

just for post request

```
app.post('*',multer({storage}).single("images"))
```

For all post routes but a few routes

```
app.post('*',(req,res,next)=>{
  const exceptionPaths = ["singup","login"]//don't upload 
  if(exceptionPaths.includes(req.path))return next()
  next()
},multer({storage}).single("images"))
```